# How to call 3rd party plugin in idapython script

Tags: python, plugins, ida

I need to use a python script to analyze some binary files in batches. In the script, I want to call some functions provided by third-party plugins, which can be called through the action that pops up by right-clicking.

How to use plugins in scripts? As shown below, I want to use the `create ur group` of the `SimplifyGraph` plugin.
[image]